# how do I separate contours of touching objects using erode?

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I'm getting this problem:

[image: http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5856/questao.png]

I'm using Python and OpenCV.
I'm trying to separate the contours of the touching coins using erode.
I thresholded the image and then tried to apply the erode but nothing happened. I've read the documentation and still don't understand very well how the `getStruturingElement` and erode works.

1. I've thresholded the image.
2. used erode on the thresholded image.

and still nothing. What am I using wrong here?

Here's part of the code:

```
import cv2, numpy as np

#1.Reads Image
objectImage = cv2.imread('P1000713s.jpg')

#2.Converts to Gray level
cvtcolorImage = cv2.cvtColor(objectImage,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#3.Thresholds
imgSplit = cv2.split(objectImage)
flag,b = cv2.threshold(imgSplit[2],0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 

#4.Erodes the Thresholded Image
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
cv2.erode(b,element)

cv2.imshow('Eroded',b)
```

Comment: What makes you think there is nothing changed? Did you verify it with image difference or something?

Comment: yes I did. Ive tried to post the output image but it doesnt let me because of my low reputation. Perhaps I am using wrong the cv2.erode?
can someone give me an example of how to use erode in python opencv?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use `DBSCAN` from the `sklearn.clustering` module to separate two or more coins that overlap at the edges. `DBSCAN` is a density based clustering algorithm, and if you adjust the radius parameter well enough, you might be able to separate the coins.

Comment: You could try a bigger element, say 20x20. You can compensate back (dilate) later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your image, it's possible that a 3x3 cross mask will always stay within the thresholded area.  Rather than using MORPH_CROSS, use MORPH_ELLIPSE.

If the coins are still "touching" after one call, you could always run multiple calls to erode, but be warned that this will have a destructive effect on your image.

Comment: I did it, I already erode the image and the contour is separated for both coins. And youre right.. the image is really damaged ahah, how can I correct the effect? maybe using dilate?

Comment: You could dilate, but that's essentially a reverse operation and you would get your original image back.  I'm on my phone, so I can't provide a link, but there are special morphological operators for "opening" and "closing" shapes that are essentially just a sequence of dilation and erode calls.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had similar problems, and found this problem via Google.

As far as I know cv2.erode() doesn't change the source image, instead it returns a new image with the change applied.

changing your line containing the erode call to:

```
b = cv2.erode(b,element)
```

should let you see the changes when you call the cv2.imshow(...,b)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old thread but I thought my answer can help someone. 
I was facing the same problem. 
There is always loss of shape property information if erode is used to separate
contours. I followed this link: [watershed segmentation OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/) where Watershed segmentation is used to separate the contours and the results are quite accurate.

Comment: Just to be more clear here, watershed does not separate *contours* (which are lists of points), watershed actually uses pixels from an input image.